# What are the necessary properties of a matrix so that the nth power of the matrix tends towards 0?

Tags: matrices

Suppose  I have a square matrix $A \in \Re^{n\times n}$.
What are the necessary conditions are for $A$ such that $$ \lim_{x\to \infty}A^x=0_{n \times n} $$
where $0_{n \times n}$ is an nxn matrix of zeros.

To add to this, when I was experimenting with different values of a 2x2 matrix I noticed that for some values:

(i) the matrix quickly balooned to larger and larger values (e.g. $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2 \\ 3&5 \end{bmatrix}$ )

(ii) each term decreased  towards $0_{n \times n}$

(e.g. $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0.4&0.1 \\ 0.6&0.8 \end{bmatrix}$, here $A^{10}\approx\begin{bmatrix} 0.07& 0.06\\0.36&0.31 \end{bmatrix}$ and $A^{100}\approx\begin{bmatrix} 2.67*10^{-5}& 2.30*10^{-5}\\1.38*10^{-4}&1.18*10^{-4} \end{bmatrix}$   )

(iii) it oscillated and reached a constant value, i.e. $ \lim_{n\to \infty}A^n=B $ for some $B \neq 0_{n \times n}$.

(e.g. $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0.4&0.7 \\ 0.6&0.3 \end{bmatrix}$ , here $ \lim_{x\to \infty}A^x\approx \begin{bmatrix} 0.538461&0.538461 \\ 0.461538&0.461538 \end{bmatrix}$  )

This made sense to me, for the integer case its simply whether the absolute value of the integer is less than 1 ( repeated exponentiation drops it to 0), equal to 1 ( repeated exponentiation keeps a constant value) or greater than 1 ( repeated exponentiation increases without bounds) but I couldnt figure out what the condition was for a generalized case of an nxn matrix.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_matrix

Comment: The eigenvalues must have absolute values $<1$.